# In general, how do I maintain a slide whistle?

Tags: maintenance, woodwinds

[I asked about lubrication.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40012/how-do-i-lubricate-a-slide-whistle) Now I'm wondering how in general I should maintain my slide whistle.

This is my first non-percussion instrument. Maintaining a percussion instrument amounts to hitting it and listening if it sounds right. How do I maintain a slide whistle?

Comment: I'm not sure what percussion instruments you've used so far, but for some there's a lot more involved.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I mostly had things like drums and xylophones. Nothing like a piano.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it needs swabbing after playing, to dry it out on the inside.

Comment: You didn't have to tune the drums, replace the heads, smooth the bearing edges, lubricate the nuts, clean the shell, etc.?

Comment: @Todd Wilcox Lubricate the nuts?

Answer (score 2):

As you have already covered off lubrication, the only real issue is cleaning, and most of this comes down to keeping the interior dry, and wiping down the exterior.

From [Eagle Music](http://www.eaglemusicshop.com/topic/Flute-Whistle/whistle-care-maintenance-looking-after-your-whistle):

> After each use, clean out the bore of your whistle and remove any moisture or dirt that has settled there. This can be done with what is called a flute/whistle  mop which is made from lint free wadding held in position by thin wire that is wrapped around it and also forms a shaft and handle.

Wiping down the mouthpiece with a baby wipe and then drying it after every use is also recommended.

Comment: The problem with a slide whistle is that the bottom hole is not normally accessible, as it is closed by the plug of the plunger or slide (I'm hot sure what's the right word in English). If it's possible to disassemble the slide, then this advice applies *ipsis verbis*, other wise only partially (clean up the mouth piece as best as possible).

Comment: And take the slide all the way down, invert the whistle and swab what you can...

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, a little cleaning and lubrication will maintain the slide whistle.